# %DROPMISS - SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I've been reading up on how to DROP variables from my dataset that have null values in every observation - it seems the best way to do this is using the %DROPMISS macro function - however I'm getting an error msg - below is the code I'm trying and the error msg

Code

```
%DROPMISS (DSIN=dataset1, DSOUT=dataset2);
```

Log

```
4665  %DROPMISS (DSIN=dataset1, DSOUT=dataset2);

-
      180
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro DROPMISS not resolved.
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the dropmiss macro before you use it.

You can find it here in the appendix (page3)
http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/048-2010.pdf

Or better formatted here:

```
/******************/
options nomprint noSYMBOLGEN MLOGIC;
/****************************/
%macro DROPMISS( DSNIN /* name of input SAS dataset
    */
    , DSNOUT /* name of output SAS dataset
    */
    , NODROP= /* [optional] variables to be omitted from dropping even if
    they have only missing values */
    ) ;
    /* PURPOSE: To find both Character and Numeric the variables that have only
    missing values and drop them if
    * they are not in &NONDROP
    *
    * NOTE: if there are no variables in the dataset, produce no variables
    processing code
    *
    *
    * EXAMPLE OF USE:
    * %DROPMISS( DSNIN, DSNOUT )
    * %DROPMISS( DSNIN, DSNOUT, NODROP=A B C D--H X1-X100 )
    * %DROPMISS( DSNIN, DSNOUT, NODROP=_numeric_ )
    * %DROPMISS( DSNIN, DSNOUT, NOdrop=_character_ )
    */
    %local I ;
    %if "&DSNIN" = "&DSNOUT"
    %then %do ;
    %put /------------------------------------------------\ ;
    %put | ERROR from DROPMISS: | ;
    %put | Input Dataset has same name as Output Dataset. | ;
    %put | Execution terminating forthwith. | ;
    %put \------------------------------------------------/ ;
    %goto L9999 ;
    %end ;
    /*###################################################################*/
    /* begin executable code
    /*####################################################################/
    /*===================================================================*/
    /* Create dataset of variable names that have only missing values
    /* exclude from the computation all names in &NODROP
    /*===================================================================*/
    proc contents data=&DSNIN( drop=&NODROP ) memtype=data noprint out=_cntnts_( keep=
    name type ) ; run ;
    %let N_CHAR = 0 ;
    %let N_NUM = 0 ;
    data _null_ ;
    set _cntnts_ end=lastobs nobs=nobs ;

    if nobs = 0 then stop ;
    n_char + ( type = 2 ) ;
    n_num + ( type = 1 ) ;
    /* create macro vars containing final # of char, numeric variables */
    if lastobs
    then do ;
    call symput( 'N_CHAR', left( put( n_char, 5. ))) ;
    call symput( 'N_NUM' , left( put( n_num , 5. ))) ;
    end ;
    run ;
    /*===================================================================*/
    /* if there are no variables in dataset, stop further processing
    /*===================================================================*/
    %if %eval( &N_NUM + &N_CHAR ) = 0
    %then %do ;
    %put /----------------------------------\ ;
    %put | ERROR from DROPMISS: | ;
    %put | No variables in dataset. | ;
    %put | Execution terminating forthwith. | ;
    %put \----------------------------------/ ;
    %goto L9999 ;
    %end ;
    /*===================================================================*/
    /* put global macro names into global symbol table for later retrieval
    /*===================================================================*/
    %LET NUM0 =0;
    %LET CHAR0 = 0;
    %IF &N_NUM >0 %THEN %DO;
    %do I = 1 %to &N_NUM ;
    %global NUM&I ;
    %end ;
    %END;
    %if &N_CHAR > 0 %THEN %DO;
    %do I = 1 %to &N_CHAR ;
    %global CHAR&I ;
    %end ;
    %END;
    /*===================================================================*/
    /* create macro vars containing variable names
    /* efficiency note: could compute n_char, n_num here, but must declare macro names
    to be
    global b4 stuffing them
    /*
    /*===================================================================*/
    proc sql noprint ;
    %if &N_CHAR > 0 %then %str( select name into :CHAR1 - :CHAR&N_CHAR from
    _cntnts_ where type = 2 ; ) ;
    %if &N_NUM > 0 %then %str( select name into :NUM1 - :NUM&N_NUM from
    _cntnts_ where type = 1 ; ) ;
    quit ;
    /*===================================================================*/
    /* Determine the variables that are missing

    /*
    /*===================================================================*/
    %IF &N_CHAR > 1 %THEN %DO;
    %let N_CHAR_1 = %EVAL(&N_CHAR - 1);
    %END;
    Proc sql ;
    select %do I= 1 %to &N_NUM; max (&&NUM&I) , %end; %IF &N_CHAR > 1 %THEN %DO;
    %do I= 1 %to &N_CHAR_1; max(&&CHAR&I), %END; %end; MAX(&&CHAR&N_CHAR)
    into
    %do I= 1 %to &N_NUM; :NUMMAX&I , %END; %IF &N_CHAR > 1 %THEN %DO;
    %do I= 1 %to &N_CHAR_1; :CHARMAX&I,%END; %END; :CHARMAX&N_CHAR
    from &DSNIN;
    quit;
    /*===================================================================*/
    /* initialize DROP_NUM, DROP_CHAR global macro vars
    /*===================================================================*/
    %let DROP_NUM = ;
    %let DROP_CHAR = ;
    %if &N_NUM > 0 %THEN %DO;
    DATA _NULL_;
    %do I = 1 %to &N_NUM ;
    %IF &&NUMMAX&I =. %THEN %DO;
    %let DROP_NUM = &DROP_NUM %qtrim( &&NUM&I ) ;
    %END;
    %end ;
    RUN;
    %END;
    %IF &N_CHAR > 0 %THEN %DO;
    DATA _NULL_;
    %do I = 1 %to &N_CHAR ;
    %IF "%qtrim(&&CHARMAX&I)" eq "" %THEN %DO;
    %let DROP_CHAR = &DROP_CHAR %qtrim( &&CHAR&I ) ;
    %END;
    %end ;
    RUN;
    %END;
    /*===================================================================*/
    /* Create output dataset
    /*===================================================================*/
    data &DSNOUT ;
    %if &DROP_CHAR ^= %then %str(DROP &DROP_CHAR ; ) ; /* drop char variables
    that
    have only missing values */
    %if &DROP_NUM ^= %then %str(DROP &DROP_NUM ; ) ; /* drop num variables
    that
    have only missing values */
    set &DSNIN ;
    %if &DROP_CHAR ^= or &DROP_NUM ^= %then %do;

    %put /----------------------------------\ ;
    %put | Variables dropped are &DROP_CHAR &DROP_NUM | ;
    %put \----------------------------------/ ;
    %end;
    %if &DROP_CHAR = and &DROP_NUM = %then %do;
    %put /----------------------------------\ ;
    %put | No variables are dropped |;
    %put \----------------------------------/ ;
    %end;
    run ;
    %L9999:
%mend DROPMISS ;
```